# Key binding to close frame in Spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, frames

I recently switched from Emacs to Spacemacs because of developing RSI, so I'm trying for Spacemacs key bindings for all common actions.
For creating a frame I now use <kbd>SPC w F</kbd>.
But the only key binding I know for closing an Emacs "frame" (that is, a OS X Windows) is <kbd>Cmd-Shift-w</kbd>. Is there nothing better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keybinding is under the "quit" submenu: <kbd>SPC q z</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

The keybinding is under the "quit" submenu: <kbd>SPC q f</kbd>.

This answer is accurate as of Spacemacs 0.300.0@26.1 (if not an earlier version). StackExchange didn't allow me to modify the original answer because my edit was fewer than 6 characters.

Comment: Can you add which version of Spacemacs you're referring to?